# How to remove under bounce in swift5?

Tags: ios, swift, refresh, bounce

I need a bounce to refresh the page in `webview`. But I don't need the bounce from the bottom. How do I make it bounce only from the top?

Currently, the values are divided into simple Bool values.

```swift
WKWebView.scrollView.bounces = false
```

### EDit

```swift
extension WKWebViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate{
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        scrollView.bounces = (scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0)
    }
}
```

It is not work for me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's realy simple.
First, you have to designate delegate like this.

```swift
WKWebView.scrollView.delegate = self
```

and follow below code.

```swift
extension WKWebViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate{
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        scrollView.bounces = (scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: I was already find it in a different question. But it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Thank you. This works, but it doesn't refresh the screen. Recurring issues include:

Comment: I load the WebView screen. And then I pulls it down and bounces it down. This is a normal refresh. And I bounce it up from the bottom. It doesn't bounce normally. But again, if I pull down from top to bottom,I can bounce, but you can't refresh.

Comment: Yes I'm korean~~

Comment: @hongdevelop 한국말로 설명해주세요. 무슨말인지 잘 이해가 안되네요. 문제점이 뭔가요?

Comment: 저의 문제점은 처음에 웹뷰를 보여줄 때 위에서 아래로 끌어내리면 새로고침이 잘 됩니다. 그리고 아래에서 위로 바운스 하려고하면 답변의 함수실행으로 바운스가 되지 않습니다. 그리고나서 다시 위에서 아래로 끌어내려서 새로고침을 하려고하면 새로고침이 되지 않습니다. 그래서 한 5~6번 실행하니까 새로고침이 됩니다. 이게 무슨 문제입니까?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201949/discussion-between-usinuniverse-and-hong-develop).